# matplotlib, networkx doesn't show disconnected nodes

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I'd like all the nodes in a graph to display, regardless of whether there are any edges connecting them.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodes = {1: (1,0),
2: (0,1),
3: (0,0),}

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
nx.draw_networkx(G, nodes)

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

this displays only nodes 1 and 2, but not node 3:
[image]

how can I show all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the nodes to your graph, not just the edge:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nodes = {1: (1,0),
2: (0,1),
3: (0,0)}

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edge(1,2)
nx.draw_networkx(G,nodes)

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]